# How to find custom xtype js in adobe cq5?

Tags: aem, xtype

Is there any way through which we get the path of our custom xtype js if we know the value of js. Suppose my xtype is urlwithlinkand i want to know where its js resides. just like if we know the client library name we get its path using this link `http://localhost:4504/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.html` is there any similar way to find out the path of custom xtype js ?

Comment: If it is your custom xtype didn't you write the code for it and know where you placed it? Anyway, another option would be a query looking for the string in the content of the file: jcr:contains(., 'CQ.Ext.reg("urlwithlinkand"')

Comment: yes it is my custom xtype and u r correct i didn't write the code and want to know where it is placed

Comment: Check this link for default xtypes which are available,
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.enums.Widget

Answer (score 3):

Widgets are registered with their xtype using ExtJS API, eg.:

```
CQ.Ext.reg("richtext", CQ.form.RichText);
```

The only way to find out the mapping between a JS file in the JCR repository and its xtype is to perform a full-text search. I don't think it's possible to define a precise XPath/SQL2 query that finds something in the binary resources.

If you have the source code of the custom widgets, just use your IDE to find the appropriate `CQ.Ext.reg` invocation.

If you don't have the source code and the widget is available only on the instance, create a CQ package including the ExtJS source (for the standard CQ widgets it's `/libs/cq/ui`), unzip it and browse the contents, looking for the aforementioned `CQ.Ext.reg("your_xtype"` string.

Comment: i found the query i.e SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE CONTAINS(s.*, 'urlwithlabel') where urlwithlabel is xtype . :) ;)

Answer (score 0):

using a SQL2 query we can find the file. Example if my xtype name is urlwithlabel then the SQL2 query will be SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE CONTAINS(s.*, 'urlwithlabel').